# Mysql Query data between date on joined table

Tags: mysql

Am trying to query data from two joined tables with a date as criteria using the query below but it brings nothing, can someone please show me what I did wrong.

```
SELECT Journal_T.GL_ID as Akaunti
      ,coa_t.gl_name_vc
      ,SUM(Amount_NU) as YTD
FROM  Journal_T 
      JOIN coa_t 
         ON journal_t.gl_id = coa_t.gl_id
WHERE CAST(date_dt AS DATE) BETWEEN '25/08/2017' AND '25/08/2017' 
      AND bs_category_vc='Rev'
GROUP BY coa_t.gl_name_vc
      ,Journal_T.GL_ID
```

Comment: are you sure on such cast as date? is high dependent on locale (country) active on mysql server

Comment: Can you post some data, specifically what date_dt looks like. Preferably on a record you know should appear in the list

Comment: This sample date_dt 25/08/2017 03:08:11

Comment: @JacekCz I cast to remove timestamp part of date

Comment: So just tried this and CAST AS DATE returns Null. You should use STR_TO_DATE as @vladatr has suggested

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Yes sure I removed CAST too.

Comment: This work for me: select Journal_T.GL_ID as Akaunti,coa_t.gl_name_vc,sum(Amount_NU) as YTD
from Journal_T JOIN coa_t on journal_t.gl_id = coa_t.gl_id
where date(date_dt) BETWEEN '2017-08-25' AND '2017-08-25' AND bs_category_vc='Rev'
GROUP by coa_t.gl_name_vc,Journal_T.GL_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO 8601 Date format would be '2017-08-26'. Try this query to see default Date format on your server:

```
select STR_TO_DATE("26/08/2017", '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then you can convert it, for example to '%Y-%m-%d' format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("26/08/2017", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @vladatr Thanks, I changed how I store date in database to Y-m-d  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out this query :

SELECT Journal_T.GL_ID as Akaunti,coa_t.gl_name_vc,sum(Amount_NU) as YTD
FROM Journal_T 
LEFT JOIN coa_t on journal_t.gl_id = coa_t.gl_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '25/08/2017' AND '25/08/2017' 
AND bs_category_vc='Rev'
GROUP by coa_t.gl_name_vc,Journal_T.GL_ID

Comment: this didn't work for me